# Regarding Open Search

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I have created an open search with VPC access and I can access the OpenSearch dashboard via VM but I cant access the dashboard on my local mechine .
how to whilelist my local ip.
And how to access the opensearch dashboard locally and how to connect with node js ??

Please provide any information on above

I need to create/add/update the index on my local node js code